# Beginner SQL question, trying to search for users who belong into same group

Tags: sql, sqlite

Tried to learn SQL like seven months ago and had to quit for a while. Came back to my baby level SQL course and tried to do the next lesson and got instantly jammed since I hardly remember what I have been taught before. I tried my best to read through my older lessons, but since these assignments are teaching how to apply your learnt skills (that were quite shaky from the start) I'm having hard time.

Assignment goes like this:
I have 3 tables with 2 columns:

```
[Users]                   [Groups]                  [Rights]
id         name           id         gname           user_id         group_id
------------------  / ------------------------  / ---------------------------- /  
1          Paul     /     1          Ducks      /   1               1          /
2          Jake     /     2          Tadpoles   /   1               2          /
3          Lilly    / ------------------------  /   2               1          /
4          Anne     /                           /   4               2          /
------------------  /                           /------------------------------/
```

I need to search for every user who belong to atleast one same group with Paul, and and print out their names.
I can manage to copy something like this from the assignment which came before this:

```
SELECT U.name
FROM Rights R
     LEFT JOIN Groups G ON G.id = U.group_id
     LEFT JOIN User U ON U.id = U.user_id 
GROUP BY U.name
```

It magically produces

```
Paul
Jake
Anne
```

Which happens to be right answer, but if you change anything or add users/groups/rights it ofcourse stops working. (I'm not even quite sure why it is leaving poor Lilly out). Anyone who could push me to the right direction? I know that I should somehow probably use "HAVING X" where X is the list of group ids that Paul rocks.

P.S.: I'm VERY new to this matter and also English is my second language.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you go back and review your old lessons to get a grasp on the basic concepts. You're not going to make much progress going forward if you don't clearly understand the basics, and the time used reviewing will be much better than the time you waste struggling to move forward without that understanding.

Comment: Indeed. Biggest problem for me at this moment is, that I have only one big slab of text and no schoolwork that is undone that I could practice with. I'm one of those who learn best by actively working on something, instead of reading. And since I have no assignments for my skill level I just have to slam into wall with these for now. If you have any suggestions where I could practice these things I would be grateful.

Comment: SQLFiddle is good for testing SQL statements. There are lots of good web tutorials out there (which you can't ask us to recommend here).

Comment: Ah I see. Is it against the rules? By far I know Stackoverflow as place that is good for asking and searching help, but I'm honestly not very familiar about the code of ethics in here (Shame on me). While I was learning Java, this community was huge aid for me so I'm trying my best to be respectful.

Comment: SO doesn't allow several types of questions, including those asking for off-site resources. You should familiarize yourself with the guidelines in the [help] pages, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And so far, you've been very respectful and polite, which is appreciated very much. :-)

Comment: Understood and thanks for lending your time! One would guess Google is good place for me to go next.

Answer (score 2):

Start with one thing first... You are looking for PAUL, because you are looking for other users in the same group as Paul.  Lets start there.

```
Select
      u.id,
      u.Name
   from 
      User u
   where
      u.Name = 'Paul'
```

Now, you need to know which group(s) that Paul is in, so now you can associate that to the RIGHTS table on his ID only.  I can also join to groups table to get the description.  In this case Paul is associated with BOTH groups which will obviously pull in everyone since there are only two groups.  However, you can at least see the steps from A -> B -> C for the relationships this far.

```
Select
      u.id,
      u.Name,
      r.group_id,
      g.gname
   from 
      User u
         JOIN Rights r
            on u.id = r.user_id
            JOIN Groups g
               on r.group_id = g.id
   where
      u.Name = 'Paul'
```

Now, we have these rights for Paul.  Now we can take this as a query in the FROM clause of an outer query to get other people that are NOT Paul

```
select
      u2.id,
      u2.Name
      PaulsGroup.gname
   from
      ( Select
              u.id,
              u.Name,
              r.group_id,
              g.gname
           from 
              User u
                 JOIN Rights r
                    on u.id = r.user_id
                    JOIN Groups g
                       on r.group_id = g.id
           where
              u.Name = 'Paul' ) PaulsGroups
      -- now, back to the groups table
      JOIN Groups g2
         -- joined on the same group Paul was in
         on PaulsGroups.group_id = g2.group_id
         -- and the user is NOT EQUAL (!=) to Paul as he is the basis of query
         AND PaulsGroups.id != g.user_id
         -- and from the second groups instance back to the users table
         -- so we can get the OTHER person's name
         JOIN Users u2
            on g2.user_id = u2.id
   order by
      -- now we can put the order in the other person's name and then group name
      u2.Name,
      PaulsGroup.gname
```

Comment: @HuManatee, no problem, but does it make sense to you.  THAT is the important part.  Just getting an answer is one thing.  If you dont understand how to get to it, then it does not help as much.

Comment: I butchered your answer to fit my needs since I didn't get it working while translating it to my SQL trainer. Few questions were raised as I was stitching it together, if you feel like checking it out. Anyway thanks again for the framework!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Basically you are going to use a sub query to select the group id (or group ids) that Paul belongs to. Then select all users that belong to a group id that Paul belongs to. It can be achieved with the following query.

```
     select * 
        from Users u
        join Rights gu
        on u.id = gu.user_id
        where gu.group_id in (select gu.group_id
                        from Users u
                        join Rights gu
                        on u.id = gu.user_id
                        where u.id = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

After sweating for one hour with all the info I gathered from here, I got this answer that works!

```
SELECT
     U.name
     -- I only need the name in this case.
FROM
    (Select
     R.group_id
     FROM Users U
     JOIN Rights R 
     ON U.id = R.user_id
     JOIN Groups G
     ON R.group_id = G.id
     WHERE U.name = 'Paul' )UG
     -- UG is now my table containing only the groups that Paul is in
JOIN Rights R ON R.group_id = UG.group_id
     -- Comparing UG group_id:s to Rights group_id:s, filtering out every user_id that has same group_id with Paul.
JOIN Users U ON U.id = R.user_id
     -- Fetching names for the user_id:s
GROUP BY U.name
     -- Grouping up the names. Done!
```

This was right answer in my case since I had to include Pauls name in the list with the other names since technically Paul has same courses with Paul ;P.
While I got it finally done, this raised few questions. Why I didn't have to use the "Users U2" as DRapp had to do in his answer? Also I was wondering if its better to use WHERE as dporth did. (Tho this way I got bit more familiar with the JOIN)

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you don't need the table `Groups` at all, because you have the group ids in the table `Rights` (you don't need their names which is the only extra info that you would get from the table `Groups`).

You must join 2 copies of `Users` to 2 copies of `Rights`.
The 1st copy of `Users` will return the rows that you want and the 2nd is the one that will join to the row of `'Paul'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.*
FROM Users u1
INNER JOIN Rights r1 ON r1.user_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN Rights r2 ON r2.group_id = r1.group_id
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.id = r2.user_id
WHERE u2.name = 'Paul' AND u1.name <> u2.name
```

The condition `AND u1.name <> u2.name` in the `WHERE` clause makes sure that only users other than `'Paul'` will be returned. If you want `'Paul'` also you can remove it.
I use `DISTINCT` because without it you may get the same user more than once.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=517e9b41a02384a522370f479b315123).